# How do I set the thickness of a line in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing

In VB.NET I'm drawing an ellipse using some code like this.

```
 aPen = New Pen(Color.Black)
 g.DrawEllipse(aPen, n.boxLeft, n.boxTop, n.getWidth(), n.getHeight)
```

But I want to set the thickness of the line. How do I do it? Is it a property of the Pen or an argument to the DrawEllipse method?

(NB : For some reason, the help is VisualStudio is failing me so I've got to hit the web anyway. Thought I'd try here first.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the pen's `Width` property.

```
aPen.Width = 10.0F
```

Comment: thanks, I got it. Was looking for an argument to the constructor